# How to fix "Could not drop object 'Teams' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had the same error with my table "Countries" and I found the solution by dropping the child tables first, then the parent one. Now I added more tables and I tried to replicate what I did before but nothing is working. I think it's because Teams and Users have foreign keys referencing one another. On the bottom I altered the User's table to add foreign keys that reference Teams but even if I were to delete those few lines, so it wouldn't reference each other, It gives me the same error when I execute it. The errors are for the tables Teams, Users, and ExerciseFoci. ExerciseFoci being a parent table.

```
/*IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Countries', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE dbo.Countries;
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.States', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE dbo.States;
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Cities', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE dbo.Cities;
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Venues', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE dbo.Venues;
*/


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Events
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TeamMembers
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS EventAttendees
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Teams
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Users
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ExerciseFoci 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Venues 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Cities
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS States
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Countries


CREATE TABLE Countries (
countryCode varchar(5) NOT NULL,
countryName varchar(128) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT into Countries values
('US', 'United States');


CREATE TABLE States (
stateCode char(2) NOT NULL,
stateName varchar(128) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
countryName varchar(128) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES 
Countries(countryName)
);

INSERT into States values 
('NJ', 'New Jersey', 'United States');


CREATE TABLE Cities (
cityName varchar(128) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
stateName varchar(128) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES States(stateName),
countryName varchar(128) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES 
Countries(countryName)
)

INSERT into Cities values
('Newark', 'New Jersey', 'United States');


CREATE TABLE Venues (
venue varchar(128) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
cityName varchar(128) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Cities(cityName),
stateName varchar(128) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES States(stateName),
countryName varchar(128) NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES 
Countries(countryName)
)

INSERT into Venues values
('Football Field', 'Newark', 'New Jersey', 'United States');


CREATE TABLE ExerciseFoci(
name    varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY,
exercise_type   varchar(50),
primarily_outdoors bit
)

CREATE TABLE Users ( 
username    varchar(25) PRIMARY KEY,
password    varchar(25),
first_name  varchar(25),
last_name   varchar(25),
age         int,
city        varchar(128) REFERENCES Cities,
state       varchar(128) REFERENCES States,
country     varchar(128) REFERENCES Countries,
exercise_focus1 varchar(50) FOREIGN KEY references ExerciseFoci(name),
exercise_focus2 varchar(50) FOREIGN KEY references ExerciseFoci(name),
exercise_focus3 varchar(50) FOREIGN KEY references ExerciseFoci(name)
)

CREATE TABLE Teams(
name    varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY,
city        varchar(128) REFERENCES Cities,
state       varchar(128) REFERENCES States,
country     varchar(128) REFERENCES Countries,
admin1  varchar(25) FOREIGN KEY references Users(username),
admin2  varchar(25) FOREIGN KEY references Users(username),
admin3  varchar(25) FOREIGN KEY references Users(username),
exercise_focus1 varchar(50) FOREIGN KEY references ExerciseFoci(name),
exercise_focus2 varchar(50) FOREIGN KEY references ExerciseFoci(name),
exercise_focus3 varchar(50) FOREIGN KEY references ExerciseFoci(name)
)

CREATE TABLE Events(
name        varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY,
time        timestamp,
exercise_focus  varchar(50) FOREIGN KEY references ExerciseFoci,
venue       varchar(128) REFERENCES Venues,
city        varchar(128) REFERENCES Cities,
state       varchar(128) REFERENCES States,
country     varchar(128) REFERENCES Countries
)

CREATE TABLE EventAttendees(
username    varchar(25) FOREIGN KEY references Users(username),
team    varchar(50) FOREIGN KEY references Teams(name)
)

CREATE TABLE TeamMembers(
username    varchar(25) FOREIGN KEY references Users(username),
team    varchar(50) FOREIGN KEY references Teams(name)
)

ALTER TABLE Users
    ADD affiliated_team1 varchar(50) FOREIGN KEY references Teams(name);
ALTER TABLE Users
    ADD affiliated_team2 varchar(50) FOREIGN KEY references Teams(name);
ALTER TABLE Users
    ADD affiliated_team3 varchar(50) FOREIGN KEY references Teams(name);
```

Answer (score 5):

You must first drop the constraints before dropping any table that has relationship to the constrained table .

You can get all the contraints on a specific table using this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE referenced_object_id = object_id('YourObj')
```

And generate the drops with below query or write them manually (or excel):

```
SELECT 
    'ALTER TABLE [' +  OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id) +
    '].[' + OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) + 
    '] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + name + ']'
FROM sys.foreign_keys
WHERE referenced_object_id = object_id('YourObj')
```

Comment: I'm new to sql and I have seen people post this answer before but I don't understand what some of those lines do and I wouldn't know how to implement them.

Comment: This is just a fancier way to generate the Drop contraint statements, the first query shows you all the Foreign Key contraints on your table by querying the system table [foreign_keys] and the Second query actually generates the  Drop contraint statements for each one of your Foreign Key Contraint on the Specified table(Replace YourObj with your table name ) .

Comment: You can then copy paste the Alter.Drop Contraint  Statements to your script before dropping the Table(The one you replaced within object_id('YourObj') in the second query) . You should be able to drop the table without any errors since the foreign key constraints are now dropped before table is dropped in your script  .